# A field is a nonzero commutative ring ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was confused when I read this statement. I thought a Ring must have the additive inverse $0$. Does the statement imply that there is no zero in a field?

Comment: A ring $\,R\,$ is nonzero if $\,R\ne \{0\}\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All rings have $0$, but a non-zero ring $R$ is not the zero ring {${0}$}.

Answer (score 1):

All rings have $0$. Nonzero ring means not the trivial ring, the ring with one element. [Not to be confused with the so-called "field" with one element, which is a phrase borne of poetic license.]

Answer (score 1):

The "zero ring" is the trivial ring $R = \{0\}$.  On the other hand, a non-zero ring is one such that $|R|>1$, i.e., it has an element $0$ together with some other non-zero elements (which of course must necessarily include "$1$", the multiplicative identity).

Comment: Yeah, that.  Meant to say that $|R|>1$.  Fixed.

Comment: It contains $1$ if it is a commutative ring with an $identity$ ?

Comment: Well, definition most authors use is that a ring must always have both an additive and a multiplicative identity.  In the zero ring $R = \{0\}$, $0$ serves as both since $0+0=0$, and likewise for multiplication.  In rings with more than one element, $0$ cannot serve as the multiplicative identity since $0 \cdot r = 0$ for all $r \in R$.